# no access to window.open html id's with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

Cannot get access to the IDs in the window.open. The window shows, and the content is in there, but var table-modal returns null. In the browser walking thought the javascript, there is a window.iframe.document present. I don't know where in the document to find the 'ids'. Why an I getting a null

```
document.getElementById("showModalBtnIs").addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Create a new window and set its dimensions

window.iframeWindow = window.open("static/issafemodal.html", "_blank", "resizable=1,scrollbars=1,height=400, width=400, left=100, toolbar=0, menubar=0,status=1");
    
// Store a reference to the iframe's document
window.iframeDocument = window.iframeWindow.document;

if (window.iframeDocument) {

let table_modal = window.iframeDocument.getElementById("issafe_table_modal");
table_modal.style.display = "block";
let closeModal = table_modal.querySelector(".close");
```

HTML content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/css/styles.css') }}">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <title>IsSafe Settings</title>

</head>

<body>
    <style>
        h4 {
            text-align: center;
            color: gray;
            margin: 0
        }

        body {
            padding: 1em;
            margin: 0
        }
    </style>

    <div id="issafe_table_modal" >
        <div id="modalContent" >

            <h4>IsSafe Settings</h4>
            <table class="table-striped" id="dataTableIs">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Key</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tableBodyIs">
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="text-center">
                <span class="btn btn-secondary close" id='btn-issafe'>Close</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, why did you downgrade? Be helpful.Not everyone is as smart as you.

Comment: When/where are you calling this script?

Comment: I edited the code to show the click event.  from a button on a web page. document.getElementById("showModalBtnIs").addEventListener("click", function ()

Comment: Can you execute the statements inside the if-statement from isSafemodal.html itself? rather than its parent?

Comment: that is a good idea. It will bypass any access restrictions from parent. As well as timing issues.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the window is opened asynchronously, and you're not waiting for it to complete loading the HTML before you try to access its contents. You need to use a listener for its `DOMContentLoaded` event.

```
document.getElementById("showModalBtnIs").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Create a new window and set its dimensions

  window.iframeWindow = window.open("static/issafemodal.html", "_blank", "resizable=1,scrollbars=1,height=400, width=400, left=100, toolbar=0, menubar=0,status=1");
  window.iframeWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Store a reference to the iframe's document
    window.iframeDocument = window.iframeWindow.document;

    if (window.iframeDocument) {
      let table_modal = window.iframeDocument.getElementById("issafe_table_modal");
      table_modal.style.display = "block";
      let closeModal = table_modal.querySelector(".close");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait till the document in `window.open(...)` is loaded.

```
window.iframeWindow = window.open("static/issafemodal.html", "_blank", "resizable=1,scrollbars=1,height=400, width=400, left=100, toolbar=0, menubar=0,status=1");
window.iframeWindow.onload = function(){
    window.iframeDocument = window.iframeWindow.document;
    // you other code here
};
```

Comment: `onload` isn't a function, it's a property.

Comment: Yes, thanks, The window was not done loading. Fixed.